# finding total number of subset pairs of a set that has equal xor??

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I recently came across a problem where i need to find the total number of subset pairs which has equal xor value for a given set.
Like for following example:

```
set = {1,2,3}
{1} and {2,3} has 1 as their xor value
{2} and {1,3} has 2
{3} and {1,2} has 3
```

Here the answer is three as their are three such pairs. Is their any algorithmic way to get to this answer?? Coz for larger inputs this work will be very tedious to perform (say 100 values). Thanks

Comment: Trying each of the $\binom{2^n}{2}$ pairs is certainly an algorithmic way, if not necessarily the most efficient one.

Comment: By the way, why is $\{\}$ and $\{1,2,3\}$ not also a solution?

Comment: we are not counting empty sets... sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: i have set with 100 values

Comment: @HenningMakholm: is there a way more effictive than this one?

Comment: @chaitanya90 I do not understand what you are trying to count.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer: pairs of subset with same xor value in a given set...assume set to be {1,2,3}

Comment: @chaitanya90  What is the xor value of a pair of subsets.  Can you give a specific example.  I know what the symmetric difference of two sets means.  Is the xor value the cardinality of their  symmetric difference?

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer: My interpretation is that he's counting unordered pairs of subsets $\{A,B\}$ where $\varnothing\ne A\ne B\ne\varnothing$ and $\bigoplus\limits_{a\in A}a = \bigoplus\limits_{b\in B} b$, where $\oplus$ is bitwise xor.

Comment: yes exactly... that is what i am looking for

Comment: @ Henning Makholm  I don't understand your equation with bitwise xor.  Is bitwise xor a UNARY operation.  What would the l.h.s. of your equation be for A = {1,3,5,6,8}.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer: The bitwise xor I know is a binary (associative and commutative) operation. We have $$1\oplus 3\oplus 5\oplus 6\oplus 8=1_2\oplus 11_2\oplus101_2\oplus 110_2\oplus 1000_2 = 1001_2 = 9$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1.** It is easier to count the number of *ordered* pairs of (not necessarily different or nonempty) subsets that have the same xor, and correct for things you don't want to count afterwards.

**Hint 2.** If $A$ is a subset that xors to 0, and $B$ is any subset, then $\langle A\mathop{\triangle} B, B\rangle$ (where $\triangle$ is symmetric difference) is a pair of subsets that have the same xor. And every such pair arises in this way exactly once.

**Hint 3.** To count how many subsets have a total xor of 0, observe that "natural numbers, with bitwise xor" and "subsets of $S$, with symmetric difference" are both vector spaces over $\mathbb F_2$, and the map from a subset of $S$ to its xor is linear. You want the cardinality of the kernel of this linear transformation.